# Get termmeta fields for all terms with a single query

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a 250+ countries term list in a custom taxonomy (location) linked to a custom post type. I need to have several custom meta fields associated with each term (country) which I already have. I need to retrieve all terms via `get_terms` or `WP_Term_Query` but need to have the metadata from the `wp_termmeta` table within the result as I don't want to call `get_term_meta` for each term individually.
I saw some solutions for getting terms sorted by termmeta etc. but I need the actual meta_values returned along with the term results.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a SQL query type of question?

Comment: I was wondering if I can use the Wordpress general functions/WP_Term_Query class to achieve the needed, instead of using a custom query.